# C function syntax

Tags: c

I'm kind of new to C and started looking through Learn C (http://www.learn-c.org/). In the function section the exercise asks the user to print out `x is big` if `x` > 10. My issue is that the official answer is

```
int print_big(int number){
    if(number > 10){
        printf("%d is big\n",number);
    }
}
```

Why is the output type an `int` and not a `void` type? Also, could someone please explain how the function is printing out `x is big` text when the output type is an `integer`? Is it because the `x is big` text is small enough to fit in the memory "container" an integer would fit in?

Comment: you should change the output to void

Comment: Just to make this clear, the official answer is as stated above. My answer would have the `void` output type. So this must be an issue on their end?

Comment: Because the example is sloppy. Or old style (K&R), when void didn't exist yet.

Comment: @Black - because the official answer can also be wrong

Comment: You are missing a closing `}`. Are you sure you copied the whole function?

Comment: @juanchopanza, you're right I missed copying the last `}`

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti that ergo doesn't follow; it's UB if and only if the caller uses the value.

Comment: FWIW [here](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Functions) is the original code showing the caller not using the value

Comment: @MattMcNabb oh, it's there! thank you, no UB here...

Comment: @MattMcNabb, just for learning purposes, could you please explain your comment `caller not using the value`.

Comment: @Black if the calling code is `print_big(5);` it's OK; if the calling code is `x = print_big(5);` it's UB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, could someone please explain how the function is printing out x is big text when the output type is an integer?

The output and the return value are two completely different things; the text is not being returned to the caller of the function, it's simply being written to the standard output stream.

As written, *nothing* is being returned to the caller of the function.  It would be used like so:

```
void foo( void )
{
  int val = 0;
  printf( "gimme a number: " );
  scanf ( "%d", &val );
  print_big( val );
}
```

Notice that `foo` doesn't assign the result of `print_big` to anything; that's what we mean by "the caller isn't using the value".  Whatever is being returned is simply discarded.

As mentioned in the comments, the solution code could be a holdover from K&R days (late 1970s-mid 1980s), before the 1989 language standard.  Until the 1989 standard, there was no `void` type; the standard practice was to make the function type `int` and the have caller not use the return value.  Although that doesn't excuse the lack of a `return` statement in the solution code.

Or it could just be poorly written code (which is far more likely); unfortunately, there are a lot of people who *think* they know C and wish to share their knowledge, but they get a lot of things wrong and pass on a lot of misinformation and bad practice.  Be wary of all online tutorials and most print references.

The official solution should either be typed `void`:

```
void print_big( int number )
{
  if ( x > number )
   printf( "x is big\n" );
}
```

or it should have an explicit return statement:

```
int print_big( int number )
{
  if ( x > number )
    printf( "x is big\n" );
  return 0;
}
```

As should be obvious from this discussion, value returned by a function doesn't *have* to be used.  For example, the `printf` function returns the number of bytes written to the output stream, but you don't often see code that explicitly checks that result; the result is usually discarded (i.e., not assigned to anything).  Similarly, `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions and assignments.  Again, a lot of people simply ignore that result (although they shouldn't).

Answer (score 6):

Ideally, the function should return void, as the function is not returning anything for the caller.

```
void print_big(int number){
    if(number > 10){
        printf("%d is big\n",number);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your function should be ..

```
void print_big(int number){
 if(number > 10){
    printf("%d is big\n",number);
 }
```

Because you are not returning anything.. Your function should be under type of `function with argument and without return type`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Dude whenever you want to return value to the calling function that time you should use int  as return type. In about code you printing value in same function block that me you don't need to return value back to the calling function.
If you want to return value to the calling function then we use int as return type see code:

```
int print_big(int number){
if(number > 10){
    printf("%d is big\n",number);
    return 1; //if number is greater than 10 then return 1
    }
    else{ return 0;//if false
    }
}
```